# Compound Parse queries using React Native

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-native, parse-platform

I'm trying to make a compound query in react native using parse, but I can't seem to do so. I want one to pull the "seated" and the other to pull the "no-show". 
Here's my code:

```
  const query1 = new Parse.Query('WaitlistParty');
  query1.equalTo('status', 'seated');

  const query2 = new Parse.Query('WaitlistParty');
  query2.equalTo('status', 'no-show');

  const query = new Parse.Query.or(query1, query2);

  return query;
```

It works with just returning query1 or just returning query2.
But when I want it to return the combined query, I get an error that URL(taken from the query) does not exist.